# Archive validation just times out - all day

Tags: xcode

I have been trying to validate and submit an app all day today, but I keep getting a Timed Out Error after the 'generating the package' stage.
Not seen this before.  Is it fixable, or an Apple thing?

Comment: Same thing going on for me.

Comment: "Your application is being validated" shows for several minutes before a time out error… All day today.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was just a Apple issue, everything went through OK yesterday by the normal means.